# MySQL: Recalculating a table with a trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers

Trying to recalculate a table every time other table gets updated, but due to lengthy query can't seem to grasp it. In reality, amount of `SUM` is bigger, it basically updates statistics page that other users can view.

I came up with:

```
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    UPDATE table 1 t1
    JOIN (
    SELECT date(FileDate) as SomeDate,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Transaction = "Sale" then 1 else 0 end) NumSold,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Transaction = "Buy" then 1 else 0 end) NumBuy,
    FROM t2
    GROUP BY date(FileDate) 
    ORDER BY year(FileDate) desc, dayofyear(FileDate) DESC
    ) t2 ON t1.Date = t2.Date   
    SET t1.NumSold = t2.NumSold, t1.NumBuy = t2.NumBuy

END
```

Desired outcome:

```
SomeDate    NumSold NumBuy
2013-09-19    52     51
2013-09-18    25     67
...
```

# of rows defined by a limit

However for syntax reasons doesn't seem to work. Frankly, I am not even sure it would accomplish desired effect anyways.

If there is a better way to structure aforementioned statistics page, I'm all ears

Comment: @peterm
I dont have that, I use HeidiSQL. I dont necessarily need precise solution to the code, rather how to solve this type of problem. You can make assumption as you need.

Answer (score 0):

**First of all** and most importantly since MySQL triggers are row-based there is no need to recalculate all statistics but rather apply changes one record at a time.

**Secondly** you can utilize `INSERT INTO ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` to streamline your code. For it to work properly you **have to have** a `PRIMARY KEY` or `UNIQUE` constraint on `date` column in `statistics` table.

That being said triggers for `INSERT`s and `DELETE`s to and from your `transactions` table are quite straightforward one-statement triggers(*Therefore you don't even need to change `DELIMITER` and use `BEGIN ... END` block*)

```
CREATE TRIGGER tg_ai_transactions
AFTER INSERT ON transactions
FOR EACH ROW
  INSERT INTO statistics (date, bought, sold)
  VALUES (NEW.tran_date, 
          CASE WHEN NEW.tran_type = 'buy' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
          CASE WHEN NEW.tran_type = 'sale' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE bought = bought + VALUES(bought),
                          sold = sold + VALUES(sold);

CREATE TRIGGER tg_ad_transactions
AFTER DELETE ON transactions
FOR EACH ROW
  UPDATE statistics
     SET bought = bought - CASE WHEN OLD.tran_type = 'buy' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
         sold = sold - CASE WHEN OLD.tran_type = 'sale' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
   WHERE date = OLD.tran_date;
```

Now `UPDATE`s are a little bit trickier since both date and transaction type potentially could be changed. Therefore we use `OLD` values to subtract values for a row in a state before update and then apply `NEW` values.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER tg_au_transactions
AFTER UPDATE ON transactions
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  UPDATE statistics
     SET bought = bought - CASE WHEN OLD.tran_type = 'buy' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
         sold = sold - CASE WHEN OLD.tran_type = 'sale' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
   WHERE date = OLD.tran_date;

  INSERT INTO statistics (date, bought, sold)
  VALUES (NEW.tran_date, 
          CASE WHEN NEW.tran_type = 'buy' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
          CASE WHEN NEW.tran_type = 'sale' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE bought = bought + VALUES(bought),
                          sold = sold + VALUES(sold);
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2be6b/1)** demo

Comment: @rodling Did it help after all?